# Convert time coordinates from UTC to local timezone with xarray

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

My question is how to convert the UTC time coordinates in the time dimension to teh local timezone (e.g. Australian Eastern Standard Time (AEST), +10 or +11 depending on summer saving)

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
time = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='H', periods=365 * 24)
ds = xr.Dataset({'foo': ('time', np.arange(365 * 24)), 'time': time})

print(ds)
```

Outputs:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 8760)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 ... 2000-12-30T23:00:00
Data variables:
    foo      (time) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 8753 8754 8755 8756 8757 8758 8759
```

Can the UTC time coordinates be converted to AEST supported by summer saving time? All time related operations in xarray should still work on the new time dimension.

Comment: My impression is that xarray only uses time-zone-naive timestamps.  Hopefully someone will confirm or contradict this here...

Comment: It seems it is not possible yet to have timezone-aware xarray indices: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/3291

Answer (score 0):

The `pd.date_range` function has an argument `tz` for timezone so what you want would be something like this:

```
time = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', freq='H', periods=365 * 24, tz='Australia/Brisbane')
```

To convert an existing series of datetimes to the correct timezone use:

```
time = time.tz_localize(tz='Australia/Brisbane')
```

Comment: Actually the netCDF where the xarray dataset is from is already existing. I received it from another source. How can I convert the "time" in UTC to time-zone aware?

Comment: ah ok will amend answer above

Comment: When I try .tz_localize on a xarray DataArray I get AttributeError. Similarly when using the .dt DatetimeAccessor (which has no tz_localize method either).

What worked for me was this:  

pd.to_datetime(ds['time']).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Australia/Brisbane')